# submit from with asp:ImageButton instead of submit button

Tags: asp.net, forms

in my project there's a `submit` button

```
 <input type="submit" value="submit form" onclick="window.form1.submit();" id="subBut">
```

after some more work on the project and while adding few `ImageButton` controls, it was standing out as un related button .

i tested an imageButton with onClick event . 
the code of onClick is still empty

```
   <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgBut_Submt" ImageUrl="~/images/sendreq.jpg" 
        runat="server" OnClick="Submit_Click" style="width: 28px" />
```

code behind

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
}
```

though seems that is doing same thing . is it ok to leave it as it is as a substitute

to a `submit` button .. am i missing somthing here ?

Comment: sorry I think I missing what you're asking. Does the `Submit_Click` fire from the image button or not?

Comment: @Eonasdan sure , it does fire and submits form1 , thats the issue , i was trying to find out here , if there's any different counter action taken by .net that could change something i am missing here or is it "just working" same thing

Comment: as far as I can remember there should be no difference. Your code behind doesn't care where the event came from, just that if fires and has the right arguments.

Comment: @Eonasdan so i could say if i dont want an old style `submit` any asp control / button that requires a code behind evet to get fired just sends / submits the form ?

Comment: You can use the Submit_Click event in the code behind, but it doesn't really matter what calls it. WebForms requires a postback using such methods so *something* has to call it. Does that make sense? You can also just apply CSS as suggested in an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input type=submit` will anway submit the form, i dont think you need to do an onclick action.

In ASP.Net world, though the events are fired using postbacks, the information is sent to server as a "Form Submit" only, the main difference i see in your content is you are trying to mix native html controls and asp.net web controls, thats where the whole confusion is.

ASP.NET web controls though provide the same functionality as native html controls, it offers extra event handling mechanism and state information, its only a wrapper upon native html controls as browser can understand only them.

in ASP.NET world you would not set the action attribute to form aswel as it is internally taken care by your ASP.NET framework.

As Kapil mentioned you can have a submit button with css which can contain an image, similar to what ASP.NET does.

Comment: that is why i wanted to use only asp Controls they're easier to implement and much more functional say in dibging approach i could add a Session variable to report on the event `Session.Add("status", "FormSubmited");`

Comment: well to answer your comment, it completely depends on your architecture on the web front.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to set image for input button, then you can do that using CSS instead of changing your button to `asp:ImageButton`

Eg.:

```
 <input class="SubmitButton" type="submit" value="submit form" 
  onclick="window.form1.submit();" id="subBut">
```

CSS

```
.SubmitButton {
background:url(images/sendreq.jpg) no-repeat;
cursor:pointer;
width: 28px;
height: 28px;
border: none;
}
```